# I want to prove this result

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $g$ be a complex analytic function that have infinitely many real zeros. Let $f$ be its restriction to $ℝ$. 
**I want to verify and prove this result**:

**Lemma**: If $f$ is a real analytic function with infinitely many zeros, then there exists $c>0$ such that $f−c$ has finitely many zeros if and only if $f$ is bounded above, and there exists $c<0$ such that $f−c$ has finitely many zeros if and only if $f$ is bounded below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=e^x+\sin x$. Then $g$ is complex analytic, and has infinitely many real zeros.

Let $f$ be the restriction of $g$ to the reals. Then $f$ is real analytic, and has infinitely many zeros; $f-73$ has finitely many (real) zeros; $f$ is not bounded above.

So, what you want to verify and prove, is false.